# calling list view that is there in a bootstrap modal from asp.net code behind

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I want to load the listview with a database table and display it in bootstrap modal when the user clicks on a listitem. How should I do this?
This is the front end code of the Master Page:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style="margin-top: 40px;">
<li><a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basicModal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span>Store List</a></li>
</ul>   
  <%--for store list popup--%>
<div class="modal fade" id="basicModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&amp;times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <asp:ListView ID="storelist" runat="server">
            </asp:ListView>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

code for ListView:

```
protected void BindProductMasterDetails()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Products_Master", con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        con.Close();
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            gvDetails.DataSource = ds;
            gvDetails.DataBind();

        }
        else
        {
            ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(ds.Tables[0].NewRow());
            gvDetails.DataSource = ds;
            gvDetails.DataBind();
            int columncount = gvDetails.Rows[0].Cells.Count;
            gvDetails.Rows[0].Cells.Clear();
            gvDetails.Rows[0].Cells.Add(new TableCell());
            gvDetails.Rows[0].Cells[0].ColumnSpan = columncount;
            gvDetails.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text = "No records found";
        }
    }
```

where and how should I call this method? Still waiting for help

Comment: So what isn't working? Your question is unclear. From what you've showed us, I see that you are binding something called `gvDetails`, which is possibly a `GridView`? Should that instead be your `ListView`?

Comment: yes gridview. My question is where should I call this code behind for gridview so that it will be displayed in the bootstrap modal when the list item is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

Use listview item databound event and call  in the edit / what ever command you prefer. Code snippet:

```
 if (e.CommandName == "Edit")
 {
     ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(),                  "basicModal", "$('#basicModal').modal();", true);
 }
```

Regards,
NK